# C# .NET 6 - simple SQL query to read one single (large) record takes forever when run is K8S pod, instantaneous when run in IIS

Tags: c#, sql-server, kubernetes, entity-framework-core, .net-6.0

I have a simple table in SQL Server:

```sql
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[MyTable]
(
    [Ticket] [uniqueidentifier] NOT NULL,
    [UserID] [int] NOT NULL,
    [Progress] [int] NOT NULL,
    [Created] [datetime2](7) NOT NULL,
    [KeepRes] [bit] NOT NULL,
    [Result] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
    [ResultFetched] [datetime2](7) NULL,
    [CorrelationID] [varchar](100) NULL,

    CONSTRAINT [PK_MyTable] 
        PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([Ticket] ASC)
                    WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, 
                          IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, 
                          ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
)
```

Please note that the rows of this table may have a `Result` column pretty large (300 MB or so).
I query this table from my application in .Net6/C# using a simple `select` with the primary key.

I use Entity Framework Core:

```
public void QueryTable(Guid ticket)
{
    using (MyDBContext db = new MyDBContext)
    {
        var res = db.MyTable.Find(ticket);
        Console.Write("Res found:" + (res != null));
    }
}
```

This code is part of my application, and is deployed in two environments:

1. IIS that runs under Windows Server 2014
2. a K8S pod

Both environments point to the very same database instance, a SQL Server 2014.

Now the interesting part:

when the record to be retrieved has a `Result` column larger than 500KB, the statement `db.MyTable.Find(ticket);` takes less than a second when run in environment #1, and takes more than a minute when run in environment #2.

Another test I performed is that the query takes a comparable time (less than a second) in both environments if the retrieved record has a `Result` column smaller than 500KB (around 10KB or less).

Why is there this difference of performance between the two environments, only for the specific query with large record retrieved?

### Networking of the environments

There is a metal server that is hosting all these environments. The metal server OS is Windows Server 2012 Data Center R2. IP `10.0.1.1`. The metal server also runs the SQL Server DB.

The IIS runs on a VM (let's say with IP `10.0.1.2`). This VM runs on top of the metal server, using VMWare Workstation 15 Player. The VM OS is Windows Server 2016 Datacenter.

The K8S environment is deployed on 3 VMs running on top of the metal server, using VMWare Workstation 15 Player. The OS of those 3 VMs is Linux Ubuntu Server 20.04.

One VM is the master node. The other 2 VMs are the worker nodes where the pods are running. The IP of the VMs are `10.0.1.10` (master), `10.0.1.11` and `10.0.1.12` (workers).

Now, K8S has an internal mechanism of internal IP assignment that gives other internal addresses like 192.168.1.X to the different pods (not sure if this is relevant in this conversation...). Anyway, in our connection string we refer to the SQL Server using the address `10.0.1.1` (metal server where SQL Server runs).

### Additional experiment 1

We added a third environment in the test, another K8S cluster, with the very same version of the app running on exactly the same configuration of pods (same YAML that deploys the resources on the cluster).

Note: in this case, though, the instance of the DB is different: it has exactly the same schema, resources, DBMS version, networking configuration, etc., it is just a different instance.

The result of the query is comparable to environment #1, running on IIS.

### Additional experiment 2

We tried to do the same query with a stand-alone command-line SQL client (Python).

```bash
    sudo apt install python3-pip
    pip install mssql-cli
    python3.8 -m mssqlcli.main -S 10.0.1.1 -U <username> -d mydb -P <mypsw>
```

If we execute these lines from the command line from the worker node (that is, outside the K8S pod), the query is fast and takes less than a second. If we execute these lines as part of a K8S pod, it takes again 1 minute or so.

So, bottom line, we have comparable results with the python client vs EF Core, and it seems the culprit is (the networking of) the pod at this time. Am I reading these results correctly?

Comment: Is the result consistent for the k8s? I.e. if you run the endpoint multiple times.

Comment: Compare the session wait stats for the two environments. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-dynamic-management-views/sys-dm-exec-session-wait-stats-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16

Comment: @GuruStron yes, we ran the tests several times. Very consistent and deterministically replicable.

Comment: Side note: You have the clustered index on a GUID column. When people say "don't use GUIDs as primary keys because they're bad", it's because the primary key is usually the clustered index and they don't know how to do any different. A clustered index on a GUID is not a problem *if* your inserts are few and far between, but if they're frequent, reorganization of pages can impact insert performance. Keep that in mind for the future.

Comment: @madreflection, clustered indexes on GUID values are not as bad if the GUID values are assigned sequentially with a NEWSEQUENTIALID() default constraint or in app code with EF's [SequentialGuidValueGenerator class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.valuegeneration.sequentialguidvaluegenerator) .

Comment: @DanGuzman: Sure, but the same people who say they're catgorically bad don't know to do that. I also don't see any indication that OP is using sequential GUIDs. GUIDs are often generated outside the database, which is one of the reasons for choosing them, so that default constraint isn't going to help. The client would need to be restricted to sequential GUIDs, and C#'s `Guid` type doesn't have that functionality.

Comment: I remember EF having problems with large columns and async fetching, maybe that's the problem

Comment: Is the k8s pod on the same local area network as the IIS server and the SQL Server? Latency maters. The TDS client-server protocol that SQL Server uses was written 30+ years ago for low latency LAN environments and, being so chatty, performs horribly over the open internet. Even worse when tunnelled over any kind of VPN such as coming from AWS/GCP services back to an on-prem instance.

Comment: @DavidBrowne-Microsoft thanks for the hint! We ran the queries against `sys.dm_exec_session_wait_stats`, but unfortunately (or luckily) the wait time is negligible (< 40ms). Any other idea?

Comment: @madreflection thanks for the comment, I agree with you in general on the GUIDs, unfortunately for the biz logic of this specific use case we need to have a GUID as PK. Having said that, in this case, my table contains literally 5 rows. Moreover, the very same table is queried in milliseconds from my code running on IIS.

Comment: @siggemannen that's my main concern!! :( Now, I am not aware of the internal mechanisms of EF Core, but I tried both `db.MyTable.Find(ticket);` and `await db.MyTable.FindAsync(ticket);` and the result has been the same so far... Do you know if EF is so "smart" to make the call "async" if the result to be fetched is large?

Comment: And that's perfectly fine. A GUID primary key isn't a problem. I was warning against having a clustered index on a GUID with lots of inserts to the table. But since you say there are only 5 rows (also suggesting that there's not a lot of inserting going on), having it be the clustered index won't be a problem. If nothing else, maybe someone reading your question in the future will be in a different situation and heed the warning on their rather large, inserrt-heavy table.

Comment: @AlwaysLearning I added the details of the networking of the environments. Your point is very valid. If I understood correctly the networking of K8S, we should be physically on the same LAN, but I think the traffic may pass thru the internal router of K8S (that stands between the pod and the DB). Being on the same metal server should make the communication quite fast...

Comment: Could you try a java program that does something similar to the python app but with microsoft jdbc driver instead. That driver has own implementation of the TDS protocol and doesn't use ODBC etc. which might be different enough to suss something out.

Comment: Can you do the same tests (python mssql cli) inside the nodes (the ubuntu vms) instead of the pods. Try pinging the SQL server machine with a large payload and compare the 3 results (IIS, ubuntu VM and the pod). And sharing those results would help. You may also want to check your pod yaml for some `kubernetes.io/ingress-bandwidth` or `egress-bandwidth`

Comment: @CristianoGhersi Can you do one thing for testing only, could you create DB server on K8s Server on one more worker node or any of them, means take much hardware configuration than other and bind the same port with the worker node. so that If you send request with physical ip or domain name and port it will hit the SQL engine. while you can create a linked networking means same bridge for k8s so that K8s request dont have to go via the physical networking. Also you can use compilation of EF to query will be happened to sql side means use IQuerable

Comment: When using `Find()` you need to compare both entities if they are available in your context and being tracked by ef or the call is going to the database. Since Microsoft about `Find()` method says: *Finds an entity with the given primary key values. If an entity with the given primary key values is being tracked by the context, then it is returned immediately WITHOUT MAKING A REQUEST TO THE DATABASE. Otherwise, a query is made to the database for an entity with the given primary key values and this entity, if found, is attached to the context and returned. If no entity is found, then null...*

Comment: Could your workload deployed in the cluster have `resource.limit.cpu` set to too small value ? Could be due to some CPU throttling

Comment: @siggemannen we tried with python program inside the pod and outside (running on the worker node) and the problem is reproducible, I am not sure how a program in Java can add any further info in the game?

Comment: @MohdIsmailSiddiqui The DB server is installed on the physical machine where the other worker nodes are installed (the worker nodes are VMs). If you intend to have an additional pod that runs SQL Server, we are having a lot of problems in using it, even to login with the sa user...

Comment: well, python uses odbc under covers, i was curious if java's handling of tds would be better.

Comment: @JamshaidK. I would not focus on the specific functions of EF Core, because the issue can be reproduced also with a Python client

Comment: @Will we actually tried to give even more CPU to our component than the CPU reserved in the other environments where the issue does not happen

Comment: I think this is the Problem, when you are sending a request from IIS server which is on the same level as SQL server have (physical machine), then it will have internal communication direct socket connection. Now in K8s, if you have Db server installed on the physical machine level and application on the K8s node level then it is not the direct call between application and sql engine. It will go in multiple steps that is why its taking time. While If we make db as another pod in the same K8s node and we set a bridge between these pods then it will be faster.

Comment: @MohdIsmailSiddiqui I agree, but this does not explain why in the additional experiment 1, with the other instance of K8S, the performance were comparable to the IIS instance

Comment: Can you answer of two below question for my better understanding-
1. SQL is installed on K8s Node as POD or Windows server? 
2. And you are deploying your C# application on two different environment ?